# kicad gcc error no such file or directory

Tags: windows, msys2, mingw-w64, kicad

```
[ 59%] Compiling bitmap2component's resource file
gcc: error: Sanchez/AppData/Roaming/SPB_Data/src/MINGW-Packages/mingw-w64-kicad-git/src/kicad/bitmap2component: No such file or directory
E:\Documents2\MSYSkicadbuild\mingw64\bin\windres.exe: preprocessing failed.
make[2]: *** [bitmap2component/CMakeFiles/bitmap2component.dir/build.make:62: bitmap2component/CMakeFiles/bitmap2component.dir/bitmap2component_rc.obj] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1979: bitmap2component/CMakeFiles/bitmap2comp   onent.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Compiled kicad on msys2 followed http://kicad-source-mirror.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Documentation/development/compiling/index.html#building-kicad-from-source

It says there is no such file or directory but there is...

MSYS ~/src/MINGW-Packages/mingw-w64-kicad-git/src/kicad
$ ls

```
_clang-format      cvpcb          lib_dxf            README.txt
3d-viewer          demos          new                resources
AUTHORS.txt        Documentation  pagelayout_editor  scripting
**bitmap2component**   Doxyfile       patches            scripts
bitmaps_png        eeschema       pcb_calculator     template
CMakeLists.txt     gerbview       pcbnew             TODO.txt
CMakeModules       helpers        plugins            tools
common             include        polygon            uncrustify.cfg
copyright.h        INSTALL.txt    potrace            utils
CTestConfig.cmake  kicad          qa
```

this is what is inside bitmap2component

```
bitmap2cmp_gui.cpp       bitmap2component.cpp   CMakeLists.txt
bitmap2cmp_gui_base.cpp  bitmap2component.h     Info.plist
bitmap2cmp_gui_base.fbp  bitmap2component.icns
bitmap2cmp_gui_base.h    bitmap2component.rc
```

I must be missing something a path or file idk any help would be appreciated.

ohh not sure if this help figure anything out but it will keep compiling to around 71% and then tell me something about eeschema_kiface error.

Comment: Says it is looking for a _relative_ path.  Which directory are you building from?

Comment: building from MSYS ~/src/MINGW-Packages/mingw-w64-kicad-git

Comment: you think export PATH=$PATH:bitmap2component would work?

Comment: Which step are you executing?

Comment: makepkg-mingw -is